# loading a page in background are not inserting data in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have enroll.html page . The code of this page is as follows :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style TYPE="text/css">
    <!-- BODY               { font-family:arial,helvetica; margin-left:5; margin-top:0}
            A                   { color:#FF5500; text-decoration:underline}
            A:hover,A:active    { color:#0055FF; text-decoration:underline}
        -->
</style>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
function inStrGrp(src,reg)
{
    var regex=new RegExp("[" + reg + "]","i");
    return regex.test(src);
}

function check()
{   
    var uname=document.scan.elements[0].value
    var bError=false

    if (uname.length==0)
    {
        window.alert("Name is required.\n")
        return false
    }
    if (uname.indexOf("\\")>=0)
        bError=true

    if (inStrGrp(uname,'/.:*?"<>| '))
        bError=true

    if (bError)
    {
        window.alert('User name can not contain the following characters:\n \\/. :*?"<>|\n')
        return false
    }
    else 
        return true  
}
-->
</Script>

<title>Enroll New Fingerprint.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="document.scan.name.focus();">
<center>
<table border="0" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><u><b>Online Demonstration</b></u></p>
      <div align="center">
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="260">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" rowspan="2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><font color="#0055FF">Enroll</font></p>
              <p><a href="logon.asp">Logon</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td width="80%" height="30">
              <b><i>Enroll Finger</i></b>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="80%">
      <p>Thanks for your registration. You can enroll two fingers for the name you registered.</p>

      <form name="scan" method="POST" action="http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp" onsubmit="return check()">
        <p>Please input your name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>If you want to enroll 2 fingers, please check the box. <input type="checkbox" name="chk2Finger" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="   Enroll   " id="buttonEnroll" name="btnEnroll">

      </form>
<div id="result"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p align="center"><small>Copyright © 2004 Futronic
      Technology Company Limited. All Rights Reserved.</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <script>
       $("#buttonEnroll").on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $( "#result" ).load( "http://10.11.201.170/data/2/sysinfo1.asp" );
           alert("Page loading completed");  
       });
    </script>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to load sysinfo1.asp page when I press Enroll button . The code in this page insert data in database . The code of this page is as follows :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style TYPE="text/css">
    <!-- BODY               { font-family:arial,helvetica; margin-left:5; margin-top:0}
            A                   { color:#FF5500; text-decoration:underline}
            A:hover,A:active    { color:#0055FF; text-decoration:underline}
        -->
</style>
<Script Language="VBScript" Src="GetInfo.vbs">
</Script>
<title>Enroll Fingerprint.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY Onload="GetLearnModel()";>
<center>
<table border="0" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><u><b>Online Demonstration</b></u></p>
      <div align="center">
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="260">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" rowspan="2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><a href="enroll.asp">Enroll</a></p>
              <p><a href="logon.asp">Logon</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td width="80%" height="30">
              <b><i>Enroll Finger</i></b>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="80%">
        <Form name="scan" method="Post" action="famenroll2.asp?name=<%=Request("name")%>&check=<%=Request("check")%>&finger=<%=Request("finger")%>">
        <Input type="hidden" name="LearnModel" value="">
        <Input type="text" name="SlNo" value="">
        </Form>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><font size="5" color="#ff0000"><%=Request.Form("SlNo")%></font><font size="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;Enroll Successfully!</font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p align="center"><small>Copyright © 2004 Futronic
      Technology Company Limited. All Rights Reserved.</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <% Dim Conn,strSQL,objExec,NumOfRecords,se_name,finger
            cust_no=Request.QueryString("name")
            Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")  
            Conn.Open "Driver={Oracle in XE};DBQ=xe;UID=biotpl;PWD=biotpl;"           

            'Query for the customer entry in FP_ENROLL Table
            strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO TEST  values(1,'OS')" 

                Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL2)

            'Query for the no of fingers to be taken for a customer in FP_FINGER_SETUP Table                  
            'Set objExec = Conn.Execute("select FINGURE_NO NoF from BIOTPL.FP_FINGER_SETUP where USER_TYPE=" & Request.QueryString("cust_type") )  
            'NumOfFingers = objExec("NoF")

            'Conn.Close()  
             Set objExec = Nothing  
             Set Conn = Nothing  
 %>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But the data is not inserted in the database . Why ? Is there any problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line from your Form

```
 action="http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp"
```

then it will work I guess.